# Recommended wifi card for Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, 64-bit

As me and [many others](http://www.google.pl/#hl=pl&expIds=17259,26994,27006,27015&xhr=t&q=wifi+windows+7+x64&cp=18&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=wifi+windows+7+x64&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=73f37432b8b8a1ab) do have problems with wifi cards and Windows 7 x64 (I can't get my card working on my Win7x64), what is the best option for wifi card for that OS?

Answer (score 2):

There is no problems using WIFI in Windows 7. Problems, if there are any, will lie with the hardware - or more likely with the drivers for the hardware. Either way the problem lies with the hardware manufacturer.

Virtually any USB adapter will work - but check first that the model is compatible with x64 OS's. There are PIC/PCIe/PCMCIA alternatives depending on your hardware, but USB is often the best, simply through simplicity and ease of installation.

Not knowing where you are makes it difficult to make a recommendation, but go to any major on-line store and they will have a dozen alternatives available to you. If you want to play safe, stick to a recognised brand: Netgear, Belkin, Linksys, Buffalo, D-Link etc... I particularly like Netgear stuff... historically it just always been reliable.

Comment: My girlfriend has a Dell Inspiron 1525 with an Intel wireless card (Internal) and it was a piece of crap. I called Dell, sent me another one with 3 connectors on it and now, it's wonderfull. So Windows 7 isn't the issue, it's the card itself.

Comment: @r0ca - I'm glad the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

**External USB Wi-Fi card** could be an option or even **PCMCIA.**

You can find a lot on Tigerdirect or ebay. Site that sells IT stuff.